# gridview fixed header and fixed footer

Tags: asp.net, gridview

ive scoured the internet for a fixed header and footer implementation of an asp.net gridview. All would appear to not work in some browsers. Looks like i might need to buy a telerik or devexpress gridview set of controls to get this requirement. 
Am i mad? 
thanks
damo

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress Controls are really good as you would also have ease to use header and footer templates.

Its really easy to customize that as per our requirement.

I have been using devexpress since last 8 months and I am really impressed by the look and feel as well as performance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: create a gridview in a div tag with overflow: hidden and fixed height (this will make it scroll), then put a single-row table at the top and another at the bottom giving the header and the footer.

The obvious problem then is that the columns won't line up.  To get round this, try giving all of the columns in the header, footer and gridview fixed column width except the last one, which should expand to fill the remaining contents.

Having said all of this, it's a pain getting it all to line up!

You can see the scrolling gridview bit in my blog [here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s301/format-gridview.htm).